# How would i convert many int arrays to string from my csv which i have already imported

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, csv

```
public class Airport {

static ArrayList<Flights> allFlights = new ArrayList<Flights>(); 

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        File myObj = new File("Flights.csv");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj); 
        
        while (myReader.hasNextLine())
        {
            
            
            String[] data = myReader.nextLine().split(",");
            Flights flight = new Flights();
            
            flight.setDateOfFlight(data[0]);
            flight.setDepartureTime(data[1]);
            flight.setArrivalTime(data[2]);
            flight.setFlightDuration(data[3]);
            flight.setDistanceTravelled(data[4]);
            flight.setDelay(data[5]);
            flight.setDepartureAirport(data[6]);
            flight.setDepartureCity(data[7]);
            flight.setArrivalAirport(data[8]);
            flight.setArrivalCity(data[9]);
            flight.setFlightNo(data[10]);
            flight.setAirline(data[11]);
            
            
            allFlights.add(flight);
            
            
            
        }
        myReader.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {System.out.println("File cannot be found.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    
    }
}


}
```

This below is the error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method setDateOfFlight(Date) in the type Flights is not applicable for the arguments (String)
    The method setDepartureTime(Time) in the type Flights is not applicable for the arguments (String)
    The method setArrivalTime(Time) in the type Flights is not applicable for the arguments (String)
    The method setFlightDuration(Time) in the type Flights is not applicable for the arguments (String)
    The method setDistanceTravelled(double) in the type Flights is not applicable for the arguments (String)
    The method setDelay(int) in the type Flights is not applicable for the arguments (String)

    at Airport.main(Airport.java:26)
```

Comment: Do, you have `String`s, your `Flights` class has a verity of setters which all require different data types, this means that you're going to need to validate and convert each piece of data to it's required data type

Comment: Shouldn't your title be "How do I convert Strings to the individual data types my setters need"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must parse the Strings to convert them to the appropriate type, for example to convert a `String` to a `Double`, you can use [`Double.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

For example:

```
flight.setDistanceTravelled(Double.valueOf(data[4]));
```

Other conversions will be more challenging, requiring you to know how dates are formatted in the file.

Often classes has a `valueOf()` factory method you can use.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot, do you think you can help with converting the date/time?

Comment: @Ilyas sure, but it's better to ask new question about how to parse a data from a String. There are already many questions and answers on this site about that. What class are you using for dates? What format are dates stored in the CSV file?

Comment: i managed to sort that out thanks, but i am struggling on how to show data from that array list on a jframe

Comment: @Ilyas If you have another question, even a follow up one, always ask it in a new question.